# Second class changes first class without returning or using a reference PHP OOP

Tags: php, class, oop, properties, namespaces

i have 2 classes. I am confused about how the second class is editing the first's properties without being passed the first class as a reference.

**first.php**

```
namespace first;
class first {

    public $prop = 'first value';

    function __construct(){
        $second = '\\second\\second';
        require 'second.php';
        call_user_func_array(array(new $second, 'method'), array($this));
    }
}


$first = new first();
echo $first->prop;
```

**second.php**

```
namespace second;
class second {
    function method($first){
        $first->prop = 'second value';
    }
}
```

i get this output:

```
second value
```

can someone please explain how the second class is doing this? it seems to defy everything i've learned.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference is the simple version (though it is not as simple as it seems). This is a good source to start http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: @Elin so i don't have to pass it by reference, php does this for me?

Comment: @Elin thank you. was a very helpful read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Elin suggested, please read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php. It answers everything.

> As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP by default, objects are passed by reference. In your case you are passing the class object "first" to the second class object "second". So PHP does it for you, and you don't have to specify to pass it by Reference e.g. (&$variable) since $this is an object and not a variable. If you are passing a $variable then you have to specify if you want to pass it by reference ($second->method(&$variable))

```
call_user_func_array(array(new $second, 'method'), array($this));
```

In that call you passed ($this) as the argument for method "method" in class second and modify the property "prop".

Comment: thanks. i've read Elin's suggested link. on that page it mentions the common misconception that, as you say, 'objects are passed by reference'. instead, $this (or any other object) refers to a pointer, rather than the data itself. this means the pointer is copied not the data and so both are updated at the same time. just as a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This function is doing the trick.

```
call_user_func_array()
```

This is call back function :- call_user_func_array — Call a callback with an array of parameters

```
function __construct(){
        $second = '\\second\\second';
        require 'second.php';
         //This is the call back function which 
        call_user_func_array(array(new $second, 'method'), array($this));
    }

    call_user_func_array(array(new $second, 'method'), array($this));
```

This function hast two parameters, `array(new $second, 'method'), array($this)`
in the first parameter you have an array of two elements, namely new $second, and 'method' which instantiates the class new second and the function method. The second parameter is

```
array($this) which says this class, meaning or referring to `class first {}`
```

In nutshell , the reason whey the first class can be modified is because it has got a call back function with parameters of the second class.

you can check out how is function works http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php